# How to store the "which java" command into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to make a "dynamic" sh script, depending on the environment.
On every environment we have Java on a different location.

What I need to do is to store the command "which java" into a variable and then call the variable in the command, something like this:

```
var=`which java`
nohup $var -Xmx2048m -jar javaProgram.jar $* -d javaProgramResource -re > /nfs/inf/app_storage/logs/service/service_refresh.log 2>&1 &
```

This doesn't work. It works when I manually put the java path into the command, but doesn't work like this..

Comment: Echo the output before passing the value to second command. Most probably there is some formatting issue.

Comment: why don't you write `java` directly instead of `$var`? The `java` command will be executed as long as its directory is in `PATH`.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your design is quite bad (the previous comment is correct), the statement _this doesn't work_ (without further explanations) is useless.

Comment: if I put just java there, I become an error msg that the command java can't be found.. 
and it's location is on every environment different, this is why i need to do it like this.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf well, it doesn't work.. if I knew any further explanations i wouldn't be here..

Comment: @LohitGupta I tried to output the result but I get nothing.. nothing is stored in the variable..

Comment: _It doesn't work_... do you get an error message? if yes, you should include it in your question (that would be a good start).

Comment: Use PATH. Period. That's exactly what you need. No need to reinvent the - square - wheel. https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bb/cs348/www-S08/unix_path.html

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf nope, I would attach them to my question if there were any error messages.. just an empty line, and then the new consol input line

Comment: Obviously, you redirected everything (including stderr) to the file `/nfs/inf/app_storage/logs/service/service_refresh.log`. So either remove the redirection (for debugging purposes), or have a look in this file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

`var=$(which java)`

Reference:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: That's not going to fix anything, as in this case the backticks and the `$(...)` are both understood in the exact same way.

Comment: I was close! My version was var=$("which java")

Comment: I have now the following problem. I think the syntax is somehow wrong. This is the error message I get:

    nohup: invalid option -- 'X' . The Java Path gets stored in the variable.